# Use onClick attribute in the xml of an included layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, buttonclick

My project has a class called Welcome.kt

```
class Welcome : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var vb: ActivityWelcomesBinding

    fun runDemo(v: View) {

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        vb = ActivityRegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(vb.root)

    }
}
```

In the layout of this class (Welcome.kt) I have the usual views and also an included layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        tools:context=".Welcome">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ...
            ...

            <include layout="@layout/layout_buttons" />
            ...
            ...

        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the included layout (layout_buttons), a series of buttons that have the onClick attribute, which should execute the "startDemo" function that is in the activity Welcome.kt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    ...
    ...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:onClick="runDemo"
        android:text="@string/text1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:onClick="runDemo"
        android:text="@string/text2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:onClick="runDemo"
        android:text="@string/text3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Since the buttons are inside an included layout, I can't find a way to get them to call the "runDemo" function of the Welcome.kt activity.

I have searched for information but nothing I have found has solved my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should give your include tag an id for example

```
<include id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
layout="@layout/layout_buttons" />
```

**After this** you can use it like this :

```
class Welcome : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var vb: ActivityWelcomesBinding

    fun runDemo(v: View) {

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        vb = ActivityRegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(vb.root)
        vb.buttonsLayout.yourBtnId


    }
}
```

if you want still to use onClick in the xml then you should use data binding not view binding